# Does the closest point on a subset change continuously?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, projection

$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $S \subseteq X$. Suppose that every point in $X$ has a unique closest point in $S$, which we denote by $\tilde s(p)$.

> Is it true that the map $\tilde s:X \to S$ is continuous?

I know that the answer is positive when $S$ is compact. What happens when it is non-compact?

**Here is a proof for the compact case:**

Let  $d_S:X \to \mathbb R$ denote the distance function from $S$, i.e. $d_S(p):=\text{dist}(p,S) = \inf_{s \in S} d(p,s)$.

We will use the Urysohn property: Let $p_n \in X$ be a sequence which converges to $p$ in $X$. We want to prove that $\tilde s(p_n) \to \tilde s(p)$.

Let $p_{n_k}$ be a subsequence; Then $\til s\left( p_{n_k} \right) \in S$, **hence by compactness of $S$** it has a convergent subsequence $s_l:=\tilde s\left( p_{n_{k_l}} \right)$ with limit $\til s \in S$. It suffices to prove that $\til s = \tilde s(p)$.
Taking the limit $l \to \infty$ of both sides of the equality
$$
d( p_{n_{k_l}}  , s_l)=  d ( p_{n_{k_l}},\til s(p_{n_{k_l}}) )= d_{S}( p_{n_{k_l}}  )
$$
and using the facts that $d,d_S$ are continuous,  and $p_{n_{k_l}} \to p,s_l \to\tilde s $, we obtain
$$
d(p,\tilde s) = d_{S}(p),
$$
which by the assumed uniqueness forces $\til s = \til s\left( p \right)$.

Comment: A possibly unrelated thought: does this uniqueness property force $S$ to be connected? It should at least force $S$ to be closed.

Comment: @MisterRiemann not necessarily; let $X$ be the set of nonzero reals with the usual metric and $S$ be $[-1,-1/2]\cup [1/2,1]$

Comment: @Ingix $0$ is not a nonzero real...

Comment: There are interesting situations when this map is continuous (in fact, 1-Lipschitz) and $S$ is noncompact; for instance, $X$ is a Hadamard manifold and $S$ is closed and convex.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, this sounds interesting. Can you elaborate on why the projection is continuous in this case? (If it is reasonable, you can perhaps post this as an additional answer; If not, perhaps you know a reference for this claim?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X=(0,1]\times\{1\}\cup[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup\{(0,-1)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric and $S=(0,1]\times\{1\}\cup\{(0,-1)\}$.  Then $\tilde{s}(t,0)=(t,1)$ for $t\in(0,1]$ but $\tilde{s}(0,0)=(0,-1)$, so $\tilde{s}$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution. Now I wonder if there is a counter-example when $S$ is connected...

Comment: You could just add a path connecting the two pieces of $S$, as long as it stays far away from $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ so it does not affect $\tilde{s}$.